# SharePoint Designer: how do I disable auto insertion of image size attributes?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm hand-editing HTML files in a plain text editor (vim) via SharePoint Designer. Problem is, as soon as I save the files, SharePoint automatically adds width and height attributes to all the img-tags.

Anyone know if it's possible to disable this "feature"?

I don't want it to mess around with my code. Yeah, shouldn't be using SharePoint Designer then, I know - problem is that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's a bug and as far as I know there's nothing you can do about it. The only way I found around it is by actually packaging up the (.aspx) files in a wsp solution, deploying them ready made to the site collection.

For regular Html editing, SP designer sucks balls.